# updating subdocuments in mongoose database

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have order collection with user_id, order_items as array in order_items (product_id, quantity, is_view).
I want to set true for all is_view (order_items) for a particular order. How can i update ?
I tried the below code:

```
Order.udpate({_id: req.params.order_id}, $set: {"order_items.$.is_view": false})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that in a single query. You can use forEach:

```
db.order.findOne({_id: req.params.order_id}).forEach(function(doc) {
   doc.order_items.forEach(function(item) {
      item.is_view = false;
   }
   db.order.save(doc);
});
```

The same in mongoose:

```
Order.findOne({_id: req.params.order_id}).forEach(function(doc) {
       doc.order_items.forEach(function(item) {
          item.is_view = false;
       }
       doc.save();
    });
```

Comment: This one worked for me.
Order.findOne({_id: req.params.order_id}, function(err, doc) {
       doc.order_items.forEach(function(item) {
          item.is_view = true;
       })
       doc.save();
    });